# How do I display magnetic field lines in 2D/3D with a stick of current?

Tags: plotting, physics, vector

I'm new to Mathematica (trying it out for an electromagnetism course) and struggling with plotting magnetic field lines using a **line** of current. Not a torturous, not a cylinder, not a circle. A line. Almost every example I see is *far* more complex and it's beyond what I'm trying to do... I know I have to use VectorPlot, but I'm feeling kind of lost. Any help on this would be welcome!

Comment: Do you mean several lines or just one line?

Comment: Just one line of current (E) in the Z direction, but several magnetic field lines (B)

Comment: Try `ParametricPlot3D[{{0, 0, t}, 
  Table[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 
    z0}, {r, {1, 2, 3}}, {z0, {-3, 0, 3}}]}, {t, -4, 4}, 
 Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]`. Do you need some arrows?

Comment: Yeah I need the arrows, so I know where the magnetic field acting upon the electric field is

Answer (score 2):

in your course you will have learned that the magnetic field at r of a a current infinitesimal dI at position r0 is proportional to:

```
Cross[dI,(r-r0)]/Norm[r-r0]^3
```

Now if we consider a current of 1 along the x ax at {x0,0,0}: dI= {1,0,0} dx0 and the field at {x,y,z};

```
dField= Cross[{1,0,0},({x,y,z}-{x0,0,0})]/ Norm[{x,y,z}-{x0,0,0}] dx0
```

If we integrate this from -Infinity to Infinity we get a field that is proportional to H or B. As we integrate from -Infinity to Infinity the integral can not depend on x, we may therefore calculate the integral for x==0:

```
field[y_,z_]= -Integrate[Cross[{1,0,0},{x0,y,z}]/ Norm[{x0,y,z}]^3,{x0,-Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions -> {y > 0, z > 0}]
```

We can plot this field using "VectorPlot3D", but note: by default all arrows have the same length, field strength is indicated by color. To get different length arrows, we use the options `, VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> {0, 1}]`:

```
 d = 1;
VectorPlot3D[field[y, z], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, {z, -d, d}, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How would I do this in 2D as well? Just using VectorPlot instead to VectorPlot3D?

Comment: In principle it is already 2D. Simply eliminate the x coordinate: `VectorPlot[field[y, z][[2 ;; 3]], {y, -d, d}, {z, -d, d}, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> {0, 1}]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use 3D graphics as follows

```
Graphics3D[{{Red, Arrowheads[0.025], 
   Arrow[Line[{{0, 0, -4}, {0, 0, 4}}]]}, 
  Table[{Blue, Arrowheads[0.025], 
    Arrow[BSplineCurve@
      Table[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], z0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/50}]]}, {r, {1, 
     2, 3}}, {z0, {-3, 0, 3}}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Figure 1]